# PHP payment gateway integration for buyer side application

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, gateway

I need a payment gateway for my php application.I am running a software consultancy and employees are from different parts of the world. I have build an application manage invoices and pay money to them. I need this to be integrated with a payment gateway.

My organization is in USA.

I checked with some payment gateways, but they need seller account for each employee.That is not possible.

My direct requirement is the cash must be transferred from my card/bank account to my employee's bank account . I want to pay through net banking,credit/debit cards,wired transfers,etc.
Please help!!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirements are such that the employees need to invoice you first before they get paid, I don't know how you can get around the seller account requirement.

However, if all you're trying to do is simply *pay* your employees, and manage their invoices through a separate system, something like PayPal could work -- I think really any payment gateway could work if you could push your requirements to the point that you simply pay your employees (one process) and handle client invoices through a second process.

Last time I checked, Paypal lets you transfer to family and friends without their percentage charge, which you could possibly bend to meet your employee payment requirement, if you can offload the invoicing piece to a separate system.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't tell us enough information about your requirements: do you need support for physical goods ? if so - who's doing the fulfillment ? you can't charge a credit-card until the package was sent which makes things more complicate than most people are aware of.

Second, what you're referring to is called the re-seller model. This model is problematic since all the major credit-card companies in the US recently came up with a new requirement: a merchant that processes more than 100K a year should open his own merchant account! (that's part of PCI compliancy required from the processors).

If all you need is to pay your employees, and being able to do so globally, there's a cool company that does just that called [Tiplati](http://www.tipalti.com/home2.aspx).

Disclosure:
I work for one of the major payment processing solutions called [Bluesnap](http://www.bluesnap.com/ecommerce/)